# Call to undefined function array_column()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am now getting the following error message when trying to run my php(codeigniter framework) code
Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column()

Comment: Please provide some actual code. Without that, we couldn't tell you what's wrong.

Comment: http://us2.php.net/array_column - only in PHP >= v5.5.  You probably aren't running 5.5.

Comment: See https://github.com/ramsey/array_column for a version of the array_column() function that you can use with PHP versions prior to PHP 5.5

Comment: you can use `array_map` instead of `array_column` like 
`array_map(function($v){
    return $v['column_key'];
 }, $input)`

Answer (score 29):

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-column.php
This is a function in PHP 5.5+, you are most likely using an older version of PHP

Comment: If you can't upgrade to PHP 5.5+ you can use this library https://github.com/ramsey/array_column

Comment: i am currently using  WampServer Version 2.4, how can be it is not php5

Comment: There's a big difference between PHP5 and PHP5.5, that .5 isn't meaningless

Comment: Wampserver 2.4 is PHP version 5.4.16, as it says on the [download page](http://www.wampserver.com/en/); not PHP 5.5.0 or above as required for array_column() to be built-in

Comment: There is a polyfill in php.net comment: http://php.net/manual/function.array-column.php#117229

Answer (score 7):

That function is only for PHP 5.5+, so you probably have the wrong version of PHP.