# php array make one value as key and second as value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
  Below is my array I have to convert first value as key and second as value, 
    Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [region_code] => AB
                        [region_name] => Alberta
                    )

          )
```

Please suggest best solutions.I am using array map but its not working.

Comment: So required array is like this,
        $result_array=array("AB"=>"Alberta");

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_column(), [demo](https://eval.in/819706)

> [(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)] refer to [Call to undefined function array_column()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18536760/6521116)

```
array_column($array, 'region_name', 'region_code');
```

for older version of php

```
foreach ($array as $v) {
    $result[$v['region_code']] = $v['region_name'];
}
```

Comment: array_column is not working.Call to undefined function array_column() error.

Comment: It's because yoru php version is too low.[Call to undefined function array_column() error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18536760/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

try it out.

```
 $arr = Array(0 => Array('region_code' => 'AB','region_name' => 'Alberta'));

 print_r(array_column($arr, 'region_name', 'region_code'));
```